# How to achieve temperature badge for weather app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, push-notification, badge

Look at this app for example.

[image]

How does this work behind the scenes?

I know you can set the badge by using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = somenumber;
```

However, this would need to work in the background for it to be able to stay updated.  However, there's a 10-minute restriction for backgrounded apps.  I'm thinking it has something to do with push notifications, but I don't know how that would work exactly.

Any ideas?

---

I'm setting a bounty on this.  If possible, I would like a *detailed* step-by-step process of how to set up my webserver to handle these push notifications.

Comment: Here's what my plan is right now.  I would set up a server with a database containing the locations that people have chosen, with a linked key containing their device name (for push, right?).  Then once per hour I would have my server iterate through all the locations and push the temperatures to the device in question.  I just don't know how to start with any of this.

Comment: I'm pretty much set up with UrbanAirship right now, as that seems to be the easiest way to get Push.  However, I don't know how to feed the 'ship. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APNS (Apple Push Notification Services) has an option of showing a notification with just a badge (no alert, no sound). You can specify it in the payload. That is how the badge can be updated.

You can have a server send out the message to the user or use [local notifications](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html). But since you want to get the user's weather information, I guess a message from the server would be the way to go.

You can also specify that the app uses background services to get updated location and use this location to get the weather info.

Here are a few good references. Once you get the hang of it, its actually pretty easy rolling out your own server/client

1. http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/
2. http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/
3. http://www.easyapns.com/

Comment: I would add http://www.easyapns.com/ as a usefull ressource for setting up a push server using php

Comment: I was going to head with something like UrbanAirship, but I don't like that the plan is limited.  I'd end up spending a lot more on getting that going than simply getting my server going on this.  However I have no experience at ALL with MySQL or PHP.  Is this a sinking ship going down your route?

Comment: The links mentioned above actually give practical examples of how to achieve it. So that shouldn't be the difficult part. PHP's pretty simple to understand.

Comment: Any opinions on whether `EasyAPNs` is easier/better vs. `APNs PHP`?

Comment: They both uses PHP. EasyAPNs provides the required scripts. So if you do not have a very good knowledge of PHP, I'd suggest going with easyapns. Plus they have a google group as well to discuss issues.

Answer (score 0):

The 73 here, is normally how you'd see the amount of messages related to the app there are waiting for you.

I assume you can set & reset that number, so they just push an update to you, saying you have 73 in-app messages waiting for you, and they abuse that mechanism to display the tempreature in farenheit.

Comment: How would I set up something of that order?

Comment: [This is a good place to start.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, they're doing it through APNS (Apple PUSH Notification Service).  It's pretty complicated to set up, but google "iphone APNS" and you'll find much better guides than what I could whip up off the top of my head.  [Here's the one I used to get out service working](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/).  It does a good job of walking through the process step by step.

Once you get it set up, you'll want to pass along a "badge" count with your APNS notification.  [The documentation for how to do that is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).